# Mathpazo Strangeness

Tags: fonts, mathpazo, boldmath

This has me flummoxxed. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}

$\omega$

$\mathbf{\omega}$

\end{document}
```

What should print is the `mathpazo` omega, and then the bold omega on the next line. Instead I see a `!` instead of a bold lowercase omega. I've tried using `\mathbf{}` on all of the other greek letters and none of their bold variants work, instead I get `fl` and `ff` ligatures and other symbols even though I know that there is a bold greek lowercase font in `mathpazo`.

What is going wrong? I am running MacTeX 2015 for what it is worth.

Comment: `\mathbf` can be used only for letters and digits, not for greek symbols. I suppose you want `\bm` from `\usepackage{bm}`?

Comment: Although `\bm` works to solve the problem, that puts a crink into my plan to create a new vector macro `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}` since I have the angular velocity vector omega everywhere.

Comment: And what's wrong with bold italic for vectors?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you call `\vec` with the argument consisting of a single symbol, either a Latin or a Greek letter, the following should do.

Note that this has nothing to do with `mathpazo`: `\mathbf` just works for Latin letters (and possibly for uppercase Greek, but not for all math fonts).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{%
  \if#1\relax\bm{#1}\else\mathbf{#1}\fi
}

\begin{document}

$\omega$

$\vec{x}+\vec{\omega}-\vec{\Gamma}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `\ensuremath`. If you have an isolated vector in text, it is math nonetheless, so type it as `$\vec{x}$`: it's clearer and not more difficult to input.

Comment: Would it be OK to use always `\vec` instead of `\mathbf`?

Comment: @Vicent That's the idea!

Comment: But then, the new `\vec` command is not necessary, is it?

Comment: Sorry!!! In my previous comment, I meant: "Would it be OK to use always `\bm` instead of `\mathbf`?

Comment: @Vicent It depends on what shape you prefer (or need) for your Latin letters. With `\bm` they would be in bold math italic.